# Displaying native tweet dialogue in iOS6 from Safari

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, twitter

I'm developing a web-app that is solely targeted at the iPad and the client has asked for a tweet button at the bottom of the page. Is it possible, using a specially formatted link, to bring up the iOS6 tweet dialogue that shows, for example, when you attempt to share a URL via Twitter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fear it is not possible to bring the iOS custom tweet popup from a web app.

But you should be able to bring the Twitter app (or other third party twitter app) to the front using the twitter URI scheme `twitter://` (or other schemes like `twitterrific://`).
You may find more info on [this wiki page](http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes#Twitter).

In your particular case, you may be interested by this kind of URI:

```
twitter://post?message=hello%20world
```

Comment: Thanks - good alternative though a shame you can't get the popup.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007899), there is no native URL scheme for the nTwitter functionality of iOS 6.  You need to use the [Twitter Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Twitter/Reference/TwitterFrameworkReference/_index.html), which can only be done in an app.

You can, however, use an app that has a custom URL scheme (such as Twitterrific, etc.).  Obviously you wouldn't know which app(s) the user has installed, so you can check whether or not the URL scheme is supported by implementing the following code:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"twitterrific://"]]) 
{
// Twitterrific app is installed
}
```

You could do this for multiple Twitter apps, and then implement a dialogue for the user to choose which app to open (if you choose to do so).